# Adding some string within a specific column in a text file

Tags: python, file, split, readlines

I want to add commas within my data below but only for the first column.

**Data I have:**

```
6.85675852     5.7928113, -99.990, -99.990,   8.083,
6.81641565     5.5877682,  10.560,   8.960,   5.465,
6.84986385     5.8423371,   7.390,   7.920,   6.026,
6.86023411     5.7104751,  16.600,  13.800,   7.311,
```

**Data I want:**

```
6.85675852,     5.7928113, -99.990, -99.990,   8.083,
6.81641565,     5.5877682,  10.560,   8.960,   5.465,
6.84986385,     5.8423371,   7.390,   7.920,   6.026,
6.86023411,     5.7104751,  16.600,  13.800,   7.311,
```

I've tried using `split()` and adding the comma, but I don't know how to write the rest of the line without messing up the format.

Comment: Show the code please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub). I don't know if your file uses tabs or spaces, so I handle both cases to be on the safe side.

```
import re

s =\
"""
6.85675852     5.7928113, -99.990, -99.990,   8.083,
6.81641565     5.5877682,  10.560,   8.960,   5.465,
6.84986385     5.8423371,   7.390,   7.920,   6.026,
6.86023411     5.7104751,  16.600,  13.800,   7.311,
"""

s_out = re.sub('(\t|\s{5})', r',\1', s)
print(s_out)
```

**Output**

```
6.85675852,     5.7928113, -99.990, -99.990,   8.083,
6.81641565,     5.5877682,  10.560,   8.960,   5.465,
6.84986385,     5.8423371,   7.390,   7.920,   6.026,
6.86023411,     5.7104751,  16.600,  13.800,   7.311,
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend writing the output to a new file, instead of trying to overwrite your existing file

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        head, tail = line.split('\t',1)
        outfile.write("{},\t{}".format(head, tail))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the input into lines and then use a regex search and replace on each line:

```
>>> print(text)
6.85675852     5.7928113, -99.990, -99.990,   8.083,
6.81641565     5.5877682,  10.560,   8.960,   5.465,
6.84986385     5.8423371,   7.390,   7.920,   6.026,
6.86023411     5.7104751,  16.600,  13.800,   7.311,
>>> lines = text.split('\n')
>>> modified_lines = [re.sub(r'(^\d+\.\d+)',r'\1,',line) for line in lines]
>>> print('\n'.join(modified_lines))
6.85675852,     5.7928113, -99.990, -99.990,   8.083,
6.81641565,     5.5877682,  10.560,   8.960,   5.465,
6.84986385,     5.8423371,   7.390,   7.920,   6.026,
6.86023411,     5.7104751,  16.600,  13.800,   7.311,
```